# How did they get from (5/3)^(log3(n)) to n^log3(5/3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here's the note I got from class:
[image]

So I was wondering how my prof got from
$$\biggr(\frac{5}{3}\biggl)^{\log_3n}$$
to
$$n^{\log_3(5/3)}.$$

Comment: I've been staring at it for a couple of minutes and I can't even imagine how a version with mistakes could end up looking like that.

Comment: In such a case, it would be much more efficient to ask your instructor directly.

Comment: Take the base $3$ logarithm of both expressions.

Comment: alright. thanks

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{5}{3} \right)^{\log_3 n}  
    &= \left( 3^{\log_3 5/3} \right)^{\log_3 n}  \\
    &= 3^{(\log_3 5/3)(\log_3 n)}  \\
    &= 3^{(\log_3 n)(\log_3 5/3)}  \\
    &= \left( 3^{\log_3 n}\right)^{\log_3 5/3}  \\
    &= \left( n\right)^{\log_3 5/3}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: ty for showing the steps. it was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Is not hard to prove that $a^{\log_m(b)}=b^{\log_m(a)}$. Note that:$$\log_m(b)\cdot \log_m(a) =\log_m(a) \cdot \log_m(b) $$
$$ \log_m(a^{\log_m(b)})=\log_m(b^{\log_m(a)})$$
$$ a^{\log_m(b)}=b^{\log_m(a)}$$

This last step is done applying exponentials in both sides. Also you con prove it using the formula for change of base:
$$ \log _{a}b={\frac {\log _{c}b}{\log _{c}a}} $$
In your example this is $a=5/3,b=n$ and $m=3$.

Comment: How could you proof it wit hthe formula for change of base?

Answer (score 1):

If we take $\ln$ of both sides we have

$$\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\cdot \log_3n$$

which can be rewritten as

$$\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)\cdot \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(3)} = \ln(n) \cdot \frac{\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}{\ln(3)}$$

$$= \ln(n) \cdot \log_3\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \implies e^{\ln(n)\cdot\log_3\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)} = n^{\log_3(5/3)}$$